# KDE Window Application Menu opens at wrong position

Tags: kde, window, appmenu

I have an issue I can't figure out. I'm using Kubuntu 20.04, Kde plasma 5.18.7. I added the application menu button to the window and when the menu open, it shows up at a random position. The menu button is at the top right corner of the window. This is frustrating because if I have a window maximized and I open the app menu, the menu has half off screen. If I'm using multiple monitor the menu might even pop up at the other screen. Any way to fix this issue? [image]

Comment: "*I added the application menu button to the window*" - what did you do, exactly?  Does this only happen in Okular or in all applications?  How do you open this context menu?

Comment: Hello Nmath, I went to system settings > application style > window decorations > titlebar buttons > I added the application menu button since I have on the taskbar a Global menu. This happens in all applications.